# NumberFormatter not working after swift 3 migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

In my application, I'm trying to format the number so that it has all 3 decimal places. I use the StringString number to generate a number and a string that I send is "1,000" The problem is that it is a response of each "1"
This happened when I did a migration from swift 2.3 to swift3

This is the piece of my code.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1

let quantityTxt = self.quantityTextField.text //it print "1,000"
let quantity = formatter.number(from: quantityTxt!)
print(quantity!) //it print "1"
```

Comment: The minimum/maximum values are irrelevant when converting a string to a number. – Perhaps the default locale is one where the comma is the decimal separator (such as German)?

Comment: You are taking a string of "1,000" and using `NumberFormatter` to convert it to a **number**. The result is, naturally, **1**. If you change your string to "1,001" you will see that the result is **1,001**. If you want to "print out" the value *padded with zero* to 3 decimal places, you are going about it backward.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm assuming you are in a locale where the comma "," is the decimal separator....

You can run this in a Playground and see exactly what's happening:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1

// assign the string of "1,000" to quantityTxt variable
let quantityTxt = "1,000"

// convert that string into a Number
let quantity = formatter.number(from: quantityTxt)

// output the "default" string representation of a Number
print(quantity!)    //it prints "1"

// now, convert that Number back into a formatted string
let qString = formatter.string(from: quantity!)

// output that string
print(qString)    // it prints "1,000"
```

And, if you change the string to "1,001" then *both* times it will print **1,001** - because that is the default string representation of the **Number** 1,001